# How can I get a list of the retweets an account did between two dates?

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to list the retweets a Twitter account did between two dates? I need to list retweets from 13-11-2015 to 20-11-2015 of an specific account for a project and I can't get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the free Twitter API - the search functionality is limited to a window of 7 days in the past. For full historical search capability you need to look at the [commercial Gnip API](https://gnip.com/historical) offerings from Twitter.